# Bootstrap not rendering Flask-WTForms QuerySelectField as HTML <select>

Tags: css, jinja2, flask-wtforms, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to build a Flask form with one field being a QuerySelectField. Everything works, except that Bootstrap is rendering the `<select>` to look like a text input field.

When I look at my page source, I see that the field is rendering as `<select class="form-control"...>`. If I've read the Bootstrap docs aright, I need to change this to `<select class="form-select...>`. I've tried putting both `render_kw={'class': 'form-select'}` and `extra_classes='form-select'` in my form class, but the latter throws an Unexpected Keyword exception and the former seems to be ignored.

How do I get my `SelectField` to render as a `<select>` field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this problem by switching from Flask-Bootstrap to Bootstrap-Flask, as the former has not been updated for several years. This also required changing `{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}` to `{% import "bootstrap/form.html" as wtf %}` in my templates, as well as replacing calls to `wtf.quick_form()` with calls to `wtf.render_form()`.